# Java Not expected Result

Tags: java, algorithm

I am using java language to write a hill climbing algorithm for solving the eight queens problem.
The code above defines a class called HillClimbing that contains a main method and some helper methods. The main method first uses the generateRandomState method to generate a random state, and then uses the getHeuristic method to calculate the heuristic function value of the state. Next, the program enters a loop, continuously uses the getNextState method to obtain the next state, and updates the value of the heuristic function until the value of the heuristic function is 0.

The generateRandomState method uses Java's Random class to generate a random array of length N, representing the row where the queen of each column on the chessboard is located. The getHeuristic method calculates the value of the heuristic function for a given state, i.e. how many pairs of queens are attacking each other on the board. The getNextState method gets the next state based on the current state, it traverses the queens of each column on the board, and tries to move them to other rows, if the value of the heuristic function becomes smaller after moving, then update the state.

There is an infinite loop at runtime. When I checked the code, I found that the getNextState function successfully updated bestHeuristic every time, but nextState was not updated. I don't know where the problem is. Is the question about the relationship between references and memory in java? Here is my code.(Sorry for the long description, but I just want to make things clearly)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class HillClimbing {
    private static final int N = 8;
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] state = generateRandomState();
        int heuristic = getHeuristic(state);
        System.out.println("This is initial state:");
        printState(state);

        while (heuristic != 0) {
            state = getNextState(state);
            heuristic = getHeuristic(state);
        }

        printState(state);
    }

    private static int[] generateRandomState() {
        int[] state = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            state[i] = RANDOM.nextInt(N);
        }
        return state;
    }

    private static int getHeuristic(int[] state) {
        int heuristic = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
                if (state[i] == state[j] || Math.abs(state[i] - state[j]) == Math.abs(i - j)) {
                    heuristic++;
                }
            }
        }
        return heuristic;
    }

    private static int[] getNextState(int[] currentState) {
        int[] nextState = new int[N];
        int currentHeuristic = getHeuristic(currentState);
        int bestHeuristic = currentHeuristic;
        boolean found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            nextState[i] = currentState[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                if (currentState[i] == j) continue;

                nextState[i] = j;
                int nextHeuristic = getHeuristic(nextState);

                if (nextHeuristic < bestHeuristic) {
                    System.out.println("heuristic after movement: "+ nextHeuristic);
                    bestHeuristic = nextHeuristic;
                    found = true;
                } else {
                    nextState[i] = currentState[i];
                }
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            return getNextState(generateRandomState());
        }
        
        System.out.println("The next state:");
        printState(nextState);
        return nextState;
    }

    private static void printState(int[] state) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                if (state[j] == i) {
                    System.out.print("Q ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(". ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is some of the output:
[Weird output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g7lu.png) 
Any detailed answers will be appreciated.

I've checked many times and still got nothing. Hope to find where the error is.

Comment: It looks like your `#getNextState` is potentially solving the problem outright, not just taking a single step (notice the printed "next state" is a full solution each time, with only that first Q on the left being misplaced). It would help to include your starting states, perhaps with a configuration that is 1-2 steps from being solved (so you know the expected steps). It'd also help to explain parts of your code (e.g. how `int[] state` is an array of the row-indices for each queen, so `state[4] == 1` means the queen in the 1-indexed 5th column is in the 2nd row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like for each itération of i in the nested loop in getNextState, there is a significant chance the statement `nextState[i] = currentState[i];` will be called,
it is called at least once for each i, which results in the complete override of nextState by currentState by the end of the loop.
That is why it looks like nothing changed.